# Plotly Choropleth in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

Im trying to do a Plotly Choropleth on my dataframe 'json' on the column jobLocation. Below is the DataFrame:

[image]

The plot shows without the data. What am i doing wrong?

[image: what im getting]

```
fig = px.choropleth(json, locations='jobLocation', locationmode="USA-states", color='jobLocation',
                             scope="usa",
                             labels={'jobLocation':'jobLocation'})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly Express [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) says:

> To use the USA States geometry, set locationmode='USA-states' and
> provide locations as two-letter state abbreviations

Solution: split out the two-letter state abbreviation from each string in the `jobLocation` column.

Based on your screenshot, try this:

```
json['state'] = state['jobLocation'].str.split(', ').str[1]
```

Followed by a modification of your plotting code to drop rows with missing location (required by Plotly in my testing), and with `locations='state'`:

```
fig = px.choropleth(json.dropna(subset=['state']), 
                    locations='state', 
                    locationmode='USA-states', 
                    color='jobLocation',
                    scope='usa',
                    labels={'jobLocation':'jobLocation'})
fig.show()
```